# Are reciprocal relationships required or simply recommended in Laravel models?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, relationship

Working on my first substantial project in Laravel, and I've encountered several notes talking about defining reciprocal relationships in the models.

I certainly appreciate the utility. For example if I have a table of items and each item has a single type I may wish to either retrieve the type because I've chosen an item, or I may wish to query to find all the items of a particular type, easily and straightforwardly using eloquent.

In some cases, I'm aware that I don't see a need to do the "reverse" query explicitly.

Is there any implicit task that will make the definition of reciprocal relationships mandatory, or is it simply a recommended practice?

Comment: If you never use the inverse of a relationship, you don't need to define it. I would still recommend defining them, just to keep it abundantly clear to other developers how Models related to each other, but if this is a solo-dev project, then it's entirely up to you. I've personally never run into an issue where an omitted definition caused any issues.

Comment: Appreciated, I could not find a source that explicitly stated this. I was concerned that it might affect the query builder's ability to deduce the correct structure for operations other than read (which is what I have working currently). If you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: There's a reason I wrote that as a comment; it's my opinion and experience that you don't need to define the inverse, but that is not valid as an answer. Someone else my have a valid counter-argument, which also shouldn't be posted as an answer. Instead, I voted to close the question as opinion-based (and there's no negative to a closed question). Cheers!

Comment: If no one has a more definitive answer then at least when someone searches for this idea again they'll find the opinion here. Thanks Tim.